# How to concatenate different lines together based on the line number into one final string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split

I am having a string like this

```
1. NAME  2. LIMITATIONS: 3. DOB  Santha   123565  2-12-2020 
4a. ADDRESS 5. CITY 6. STATE 7. PIN nagar RJY AP 34567
```

I want the o/p as

```
1. NAME  2. LIMITATIONS: 3. DOB
Santha   123565  2-12-2020 
4a. ADDRESS 5. CITY 6. STATE 7. PIN
nagar RJY AP 34567
```

Can anyone help me plz thanks in advance

Edit :

Actually from the code which I wrote myside(which I cant show) I will get two multiline strings
one is i and other j

```
print(i) 
    1. NAME  2. LIMITATIONS: 3. DOB
    4a. ADDRESS 5. CITY 6. STATE 7. PIN
print(j)
    Santha   123565  2-12-2020 
    nagar RJY AP 34567
```

if print(i,j) I am getting as I shown in the above question

What I exactly want is print i and then j and so on and want to store all in one varaiable called text

2nd edit:

I am having two strings i and j

```
print(i) 
"A","B","c","d"
"e","f","g"


print(j)
"a","B","c"
"D","e","f"
```

So here what I want to print k as a variable

```
"A","B","c","d"
"a","B","c"
"e","f","g"
"D","e","f"
```

Note: No matter what the strings are I need a logic

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Can't understand from your example where should string be split. Also please provide code snippet that shows your efforts.

Comment: So you want to insert two newline characters, one after DOB and the other after PIN?

Comment: Please add a sample code showing your effort so that we can help you for it.

Comment: @L.Grozinger  see I had edited the question could you plz help me

Comment: to concatenate strings use e.g. `i + j`

Comment: @SUTerliakov  I cant add code as it is no longer related to question I had edited the question could you please see once and help me

Comment: @L.Grozinger not concatenating I want to get first row i and second row j and third row i forth row j and so on and want to store the same sequence of strings in a varaible

Answer (score 0):

The real final question

```
i = "This is i's first line \nNow this is i's second line"
j = "This is j's first line \nNow this is j's second line"
final_text = ""
for x in range(int(len(i.split("\n")))):
    final_text+= i.split("\n")[x] +"\n"+ j.split("\n")[x]+ "\n"
print(final_text)
```

Code Answering the final Question

```
text = "1. NAME  2. LIMITATIONS: 3. DOB  Santha   123565  2-12-2020 4a. ADDRESS 5. CITY 6. STATE 7. PIN nagar RJY AP 34567"
pieces_of_text = text.split(" ")
final_text = ""
in_first_string = True
first_string = ""
second_string = ""
for a in pieces_of_text:
    if a == "DOB":
        final_text+= a+"\n"
        in_first_string = False
    elif a == "4a.":
        final_text+= "\n" + a
        in_first_string = True
    elif a == "PIN":
        final_text+= a+"\n"
        in_first_string = False
    else:
        final_text += a +" "
    if in_first_string:
        first_string+=(str(a+" "))
    else:
        second_string+=(str(a+" "))
print(final_text)
print(first_string)
second_string = second_string[3:].split("PIN")
second_string = second_string[0]+second_string[1]
print(second_string)
```

So im guessing that DOB 4a. and PIN will stay the same and using that I will build my code. If that's not true this wont work.

```
text = "1. NAME  2. LIMITATIONS: 3. DOB  Santha   123565  2-12-2020 4a. ADDRESS 5. CITY 6. STATE 7. PIN nagar RJY AP 34567"
pieces_of_text = text.split(" ")
final_text = ""
for a in pieces_of_text:
    if a == "DOB":
        final_text+= a+"\n"
    elif a == "4a.":
        final_text+= "\n" + a
    elif a == "PIN":
        final_text+= a+"\n"
    else:
        final_text += a +" "
print(final_text)
```